# How to use matplotlib.pyplot.xlim() with timestamps?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

i am trying to show a plot with timestamps on the x-axis. I would like to to show a smaller timeframe but get the 'SyntaxError: invalid token' error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import feather
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.read_feather('HAN_2019_Sept_Var32_oP_4H_L1.feather')
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df1.timestamp ,df1.Differenz_Q_UEH1_Eco, label='oP 4H')
ax.legend()
ax.set(xlabel='timestamp', ylabel='Differenz_Q_UEH1_Eco',title='')

plt.xlim([2019-09-01 00:00:00, 2019-09-01 00:04:00])
ax.grid()
```

Comment: Can you please share your data or some part of data

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from a notice that:

```
plt.xlim([2019-09-01 00:00:00, 2019-09-01 00:04:00])
```

is not any valid *python* instruction.

It causes the following error message:

```
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted
```

I assume that your *timestamp* column is of *timestamp* type,
so also both *x* limits should be passed also as values of *timestamp*
type.

The most intuitive way is to convert both datetime strings
(even without seconds) to *timestamp* and then pass them to *xlim*:

```
plt.xlim([pd.to_datetime('2019-09-01 00:00'), pd.to_datetime('2019-09-01 00:04')])
```

Or maybe *xlim* will accept these parameters as **strings**?
Try also this variant.

Another option is to select from your DataFrame only rows from
your "wanted" period and create a plot from these (narrowed down)
data.